# Why are my rows in my Jtable not being displayed?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I don't understand why, when I execute my request, only the headers of my jtable are correct but the row aren't display.

Here is my code

```
private void jButtonRequeteSqlExecuterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
    try {

        //Taking the query from a txt
        String query = jTextPaneRequeteSql.getText();

        // Initialisation request time
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Creating a statement
        Connection con = getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);            

        //Little manipulation to get the number of row
        rs.last();
        int rowCount = rs.getRow();

        //Calculate the time
        long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        //Get the model
        jTableRequeteSql.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));

        //display the time
        jLabelRequeteSql.setText("La requête à été exécuter en " + totalTime + " ms et a retourné " + rowCount + " ligne(s)");
        System.out.println("La requête à été exécuter en " + totalTime + " ms et a retourné " + rowCount + " ligne(s)");

        //Refresh the display
        jTableRequeteSql.revalidate();
        jTableRequeteSql.repaint();

                //Closing connection
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                con.close();


          }
          catch (SQLException e) {
              //Dans le cas d'une exception, on affiche une pop-up et on efface le contenu
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ERREUR ! ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          }

}
```

To understand better my code you should know :
getConnection () is a function that returns the con (simple connection to database function).

The buildTableModel(rs) function is a function to make a dynamic table with number of columns and their names dynamically :

```
 public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
throws SQLException {

ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

// names of columns
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
    columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
}

// data of the table
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
    }
    data.add(vector);
}

return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

}

Comment: Is there data in the `ResultSet`. Consider putting a `System.out.println` statement in the two loops to see if anything is actually been loaded from the database

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [How to use prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: And [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as you're risking leaving your resources open if something goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, I can see clearly now ...

```
rs.last();
int rowCount = rs.getRow();
```

you've moved the cursor to the end of the `ResultSet`, but you've not reset it, so when you call `ResultSet#next`, it fails, as it's already at the end.

You need to use [`ResultSet#beforeFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst()) to reset the cursor to the start of the `ResultSet`

And because your code is annoying me...

```
//Taking the query from a txt
String query = jTextPaneRequeteSql.getText();

try (Connection con = getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {

    // Initialisation request time
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Little manipulation to get the number of row
    rs.last();
    int rowCount = rs.getRow();

    //Calculate the time
    long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    rs.beforeFirst();
    //Get the model
    jTableRequeteSql.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));

    //display the time
    jLabelRequeteSql.setText("La requête à été exécuter en " + totalTime + " ms et a retourné " + rowCount + " ligne(s)");
    System.out.println("La requête à été exécuter en " + totalTime + " ms et a retourné " + rowCount + " ligne(s)");

    //Refresh the display
    jTableRequeteSql.revalidate();
    jTableRequeteSql.repaint();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    //Dans le cas d'une exception, on affiche une pop-up et on efface le contenu
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ERREUR ! ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

See [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks lots it worked :D I shouldn't program after 2am XD Just a detail, in your code i moved this :       // Initialisation request time
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();       Before the try

Comment: And in your code your are not closing the connection anymore... Why ?

Comment: I am closing the resources, but it’s been done automatically. See the link for the try-with-resources